# How to cross apply a simple array using collection reference in ADF?

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory to ingest data from a JSON REST API. The JSON elements are formatted like this:

```
{
    "order_id": 1
    "date": "20170122",
    "product_ids": [123, 124, 125]
}
```

I want to store this data as 3 rows in a SQL table, one for each element in the product_ids array. My expected output would look like this:

```
  order_id     date     product_id  
 ========== ========== ============ 
         1   20170122          123  
         1   20170122          124  
         1   20170122          125
```

I know I can do that with a Data Flow, but ideally I'd like to handle it with a simple Copy Data activity. However, I can't quite figure out how to get that to work.

I've seen the documentation about Collection references, but all the examples I can find use more complicated arrays with named elements, such as:

```
{
    "order_id": 1
    "date": "20170122",
    "products": [
        {
            "prod": "p1",
            "price": 23
        },
        {
            "prod": "p2",
            "price": 13
        }
    ]
}
```

For this more complicated case, you can set the collection reference to `$['products']` and then extract `['prod']` and `['price']`. Similary, I use `$['product_ids']` as the collection reference. But what to use for the mappings? Using `[0]`, I only get one row with product_id 123. If I use `[*]`, I get one row with a NULL in the product_id column.

Comment: what is your target here? can you provide sample expected output?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I have edited my question to include sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy activity advanced editor and collection reference is only supported for the Array of Objects.

[image]

Your array is a simple array without any objects. So, copy activity won't support this kind of array.

However, you can try below workaround in this case. But this involves complex and time taking operations like loops and SQL scripts, and this only works when the JSON rows are less than 5000. **Dataflow is the better option than this**.

First give your API to a web activity and get the required JSON from it. Give the `product_ids` array from the web activity output to a For-Each activity and check the Sequential checkbox.

Here, I am using lookup to get the JSON and given `product_ids` array from lookup output.

[image]

Create an array variable in the variables section of the pipeline.

Inside for-each activity, take an append variable activity to the created array variable and give the below expression.

```
@json(concat(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]),'"product_ids":')[0],'"product_id":',item(),'}'))
```

[image]

After for-loop, it will generate the JSON array like below.

```
[
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "date": "20170122",
            "product_id": 123
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "date": "20170122",
            "product_id": 124
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "date": "20170122",
            "product_id": 125
        }
]
```

Next, take a copy activity and at source, use SQL dataset with below script in the query option.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max) = N'@{variables('myjson')}';

SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON (@json)  
WITH (   
              order_id int '$.order_id' ,  
              date varchar(32) '$.date',  
              product_id int '$.product_id'
 );
```

In the copy activity sink, give your target SQL table and debug the pipeline. It will give you expected result like below.

[image]